# What is this dmesg error?

Tags: dmesg

```
1428.732482] mmc0: ADMA error
[ 1428.732485] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
[ 1428.732489] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000020 | Version:  0x00000603
[ 1428.732493] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000020
[ 1428.732497] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x03096450 | Trn mode: 0x0000002b
[ 1428.732501] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x01ff0000 | Host ctl: 0x00000017
[ 1428.732505] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
[ 1428.732509] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000207
[ 1428.732512] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000e | Int stat: 0x00000000
[ 1428.732516] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x03ff008b | Sig enab: 0x03ff008b
[ 1428.732520] mmc0: sdhci: ACmd stat: 0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
[ 1428.732524] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x25fec8bf | Caps_1:   0x10002078
[ 1428.732528] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x0000193a | Max curr: 0x005800c8
[ 1428.732532] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000900 | Resp[1]:  0x01dbd37f
[ 1428.732536] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x32db7900 | Resp[3]:  0x00000900
[ 1428.732538] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x00000000
[ 1428.732542] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000007 | ADMA Ptr: 0x3403f208
[ 1428.732543] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
```

Good day. Will somebody help me? What is this error? How to check?

Comment: mmc0 refers to an SD memory card.

Comment: I know. but is this something serious? I have the system on an SD card.

Comment: Good day. Will somebody help me? What is this error? How to check?